# The component that uses Router does not show up on Button click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing the page where a user can select between two options: Button 1 redirects to `TestOption.js` or Button 2 redirects to TestOption2 (currently, `TestOption` is used for testing purposes). The default page is `SelectionPage`.

The problem is with the Button click event. In `SelectionPage`, I'm using `onClick={this.props.clickBtn}`. When I click on the button, it opens a new page with `Header` only, but without `Main`. I assume that the problem is caused by `Router` that I use in `Main`. But I don't know how to fix it.

Could someone point me to an error?

Thanks.

The code of App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import TestOption from './components/TestOption';
import SelectionPage from './components/SelectionPage';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    renderView: 0
  };

  clickBtn = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      renderView: +e.target.parentNode.value
    });
  };


  render() {

    switch (this.state.renderView) {
      case 1:
        return (
          < TestOption />
        );
      case 2:
        return (
          < TestOption />
        );
      default:
        return (
          < SelectionPage clickBtn={this.clickBtn} />
        );
    }
  }

}

export default App;
```

**The code of SelectionPage.js:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";


const styles = theme => ({
  card: {
    minWidth: 350
  },
  button: {
    fontSize: "12px",
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    minWidth: 350
  },
  extendedIcon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: '20px',
    minWidth: 350,
    margin: theme.spacing.unit
  },
});


class SelectionPage extends Component {

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Grid
          container
          spacing={0}
          direction="column"
          alignItems="center"
          justify="center"
          style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
        >
          <Card className={classes.card}>
            <Typography align="center" className={classes.title}>
              Select the option
            </Typography>
            <CardContent>
              <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  size="medium"
                  color="primary"
                  className={classes.button}
                  value="1"
                  onClick={this.props.clickBtn}
                >
                  Option 1
                </Button>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  size="medium"
                  color="primary"
                  className={classes.button}
                  value="2"
                  onClick={this.props.clickBtn}
                >
                  Option 2
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SelectionPage);
```

**The code of TestOption:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './../App.css';
import { Header } from './Header';
import { Main } from './Main';


class TestOption extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="Site-content">
          <div className="App-header">
            <Header />
          </div>
          <div className="main">
              <Main />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TestOption;
```

**The code of Main.js:**

```
import '../App.css';
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Tree } from './Tree';
import { Tabular } from './Tabular';

export function Main() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Router>
                  <Route path='/.' component={Tree} />
                  <Route path='/tabular' component={Tabular} />
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Are you able to view your console.log on browser console when you click the button?

Comment: @MaddyBlacklisted: Yes, and if I just put a `div` component with some text into `Main` (instead of `Router`), then I can see this text properly. It just does not show `Tree`.

Comment: You should simplify your code to test your functionnalities. As you see here https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-waterfall-ce82e, it should works properly.

Comment: @robinvrd: I already simplified it as much as possible. I cannot drop any of classes because then the logic will break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<Route path='/tabular' component={Tabular} />
<Route path='/' component={Tree} />
```

changing the order of `<Route>` will fix your issue.

Comment: I added `exact` to `<Route path='/' exact component={Tree} />` and now it shows Tree. But this approach does not work with `Tabular`. It redirects back to the `SelectionPage`.

Comment: What do you mean by "changing the order of Route"?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Why the order matters? Now, `Tree` works correctly. But when I click to redirect to `Tabular` it goes to address `localhost:3000/tabular` (good!) and shows `SelectionPage` instead of `Tabular`. Why does it happen?

Comment: /tabular will be mapped to /tabular and /*. so since you wrote /* first. first match first serve. Also /* is same as /

Comment: So, then how can I open `Tabular` (`/tabular`) when I click on a component that call it, and open `Tree` (`/`) when I click on another component that calls it?

Comment: use exact path for both of them

Comment: Maybe you have an example?

Comment: ok, now your loading wrong component but routing is improved. i didn't see that.
if you can help me with your component flow....coz above is quite confusing since App.js never used in your code. but one thing is sure that /tabular is opening correct component since in App.js your default rendering is SelectionPage so it is opening that.

Comment: Hi. I created a demo web app in codesandbox.io and opened a new question related to this discuss: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62627895/react-router-redirect-is-not-redirecting-a-user-to-proper-pages